# Controller Doubled on URL (ASP MVC 2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a form tag using Url.Action on my FormUser view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="..<%: Url.Action(ViewData("FormMode"), "Master") %>" method="post">
     {some form code}
</form>
```

the ViewData("FormMode") is generated on my controller whether it's edit or create new. Here's my Master controller code:

```
Function FormAddUser() As ActionResult
        ViewData("AreaMenu") = sideBarModel.createLineMenu
        ViewData("RoleOption") = RoleOption()
        ViewData("FormMode") = "i_AddUser"
        Return View("Form_User")
    End Function

    Function EditUser() As ActionResult
        ViewData("AreaMenu") = sideBarModel.createLineMenu
        ViewData("ReadOnly") = "readonly"
        ViewData("FormMode") = "u_UpdateUser"
        ViewData("RoleOption") = RoleOption()

        Dim dt_user As DataTable = masterCommand.get_UserDetail(Request.QueryString("id"))

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt_user.Rows
            ViewData("v_UserName") = dr("User_Name")
            ViewData("v_Role") = dr("ID_Role")
        Next

        Return View("Form_User")
    End Function
```

if I'm calling the FormAddUser function, the submit button will have correct URL action, that is

> ../Master/i_AddUser

but if i try to call the EditUser function, which is by using this URL pattern

> ../Master/EditUser/?id=Alex

The submit button on the form will doubling the Master

> ../Master/Master/u_UpdateUser

I tried to configure the URL pattern using this

```
routes.MapRoute( _
            "EditUser", _
            "{controller}/{action}/{*id}", _
            New With {.controller = "Master", .action = "EditUser", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        )
```

but it seems not working. What can I do? I'm using MVC 2. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is it you are trying to do here? You seem to be setting the forms target action and controller from ViewData dynamically and you are not using any models for your forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to cast `ViewData` as String before calling Url helper.

```
Url.Action(ViewData("formmode").ToString(), "Master")
```

Otherwise is going to return Object at runtime.

Comment: wow, that was a simple fix, thanks. I really don't have any clue about that. Still trying to understand the ASP MVC. thank you sir, for real!